# Configuring session cookies in Weblogic

Tags: java, session, cookies, weblogic

I'm pretty new to Weblogic and I'm currently trying to convert a web application that I've been running using Tomcat on my local machine to work with Weblogic since our production servers are weblogic.  I'm having trouble configuring weblogic.xml so that I can access session attributes.  Currently my weblogic.xml looks like this...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <session-descriptor>
        <cookie-name>JSESSIONID</cookie-name>
        <cookie-domain>localhost</cookie-domain>
        <cookie-path>/domain</cookie-path>
        <cookie-secure>false</cookie-secure>
        <url-rewriting-enabled>false</url-rewriting-enabled>
    </session-descriptor>
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <precompile>false</precompile>
        <precompile-continue>true</precompile-continue>
        <keepgenerated>false</keepgenerated>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/domain</context-root>
    <library-ref>
        <library-name>springLib</library-name>
    </library-ref>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

This does not seem to be working when I run locally.  Do I need to include the port number in the cookie-domain (i.e. localhost:7001)?  This seems to be the only glitch I haven't been able to resolve.  If anyone has any ideas please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you leave it blank?

Comment: The docs say `The domain name must have at least two components. Setting a name to *.com or *.net is not valid.` I think you should try leaving it blank a JoseK suggests.

Comment: Or you could omit the _cookie-domain_ element alltogether. The default value is fine for most cases. See the [weblogic.xml documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP613) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish what I needed by making the following changes:

```
<cookie-domain></cookie-domain>
<cookie-path>/</cookie-path>
```